# Vue.js Enlarge an image by on click on it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vue.js

I' m trying to make a gallery.

How can i enlarge the images inside the gallery by clicking on them? i have an array of objects with 3 key value pairs ( id,src,alt). I guess i have to use transition-group but i really don't know how to move on.
That's my loop

```
        <img 
            v-for="image in images" 
            v-bind:key="image.id" 
            v-bind:src="image.src" 
            v-bind:alt="image.alt"
        />
```

Thanks

Comment: please search for  `lightbox in vue js`

Comment: Ideally, you would have a thumbnail w/ a click handler. The click handler would trigger a CSS change, causing your enlarged image to unhide, thus 'enlarging' it.

The enlarged version would just be a modal <div class="imgbox"><img/></div> with an image  tag inside.
The thumbnail's click event handler would toggle the imgbox class from 'display:none' to 'display:block'.

You can research Modals/Dialogs in CSS/HTML and implement a Vue version with little effort.

Comment: https://itnext.io/click-images-and-show-them-in-full-size-a-reusable-solution-in-vue-8b042f646809
this my be your answer